# Bind the data context of user control to main window in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls, datacontext

I'm trying to bind the data context of the user control to the data context of the window. But somehow in the code behind of the user control, the data context is null. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Dialogs.SettingsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dialogs="clr-namespace:MyApp.Dialogs"
        Title="Settings">

    <dialogs:Usercontrol DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></dialogs:Usercontrol>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `MyApp.Dialogs.Usercontrol` has defined its own `DataContext` in its XAML/code-behind, and you are trying to override this, then you can do this:

```
<dialogs:Usercontrol DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext}" />
```

If `MyApp.Dialogs.Usercontrol` does not have its `DataContext` explicitly defined, then you don't need to do this at all - it will automatically inherit from its parent (Window).

Comment: My frame user control does not get the Window's DataContext automatically.

Answer (score 3):

{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext}

However, the usercontrol should automatically inherit the datacontext of the window!

Answer (score 1):

if you see the `DataContext` being null in the codebehind your're checking at a time, when the binding is not yet resolved. You don't happen to check in the constructor do you?

With the binding you got the DataContext should be of Type `MyApp.Dialogs.Usercontrol`. If you want it to have the same DataContext as the Window just remove the binding altogether.

Comment: Exactly! The problem is I'm trying to cast the `DataContext` to a variable in the code-behind of the user control! And that's where the problem is! So then where in the code-behind of the user-control should I cast and assign the data context to that variable?

Comment: I would say it should be all loaded by the time `Load` event triggers. @Vahid

Comment: @Jai The problem I have is this: I have two radio buttons in my user control which have an `Checked` event that changes `DataContext`. Now as soon as the component initializes, the `Checked` event fires and tries to change the null data context! For now I'm just simply returning from the event when the data context is null to avoid exceptions but I know there must be a more decent way to handle this!

Comment: @Vahid What does changing the "null data context" mean? If you have a new DataContext, it doesn't matter if the original value is null or not, does it?

Comment: @Vahid It would really help people know how to help you if you just post the part of the codes for your radio buttons, as well as the event itself.

Comment: @Jai Thanks Jai, it seems the problem is solved! It seems I was trying to cast the null data context into a variable in the constructor and then use in the event methods of radio buttons!